# Jsoup can't select input class

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I got this HTML:

```
<div class="responsive_friendblocks">
<div class="friendBlock persona offline" href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198312248750" data-miniprofile="351983022">
    <div class="manage_friend_checkbox" style="display: none;">
        <input class="friendCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="friendbox_[U:1:351983022]" name="friends[76561198312248750]" data-steamid="76561198312248750" value="1">
    </div>
```

I want to get the "data-steamid" using Jsoup. I don't know how to get there. The Code works fine with the "data-miniprofile". It just does not return anything for "data-steamid".

This is my Android Code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        // Connect to website
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        Elements MiniProfile = document.select("div.friendBlock.persona.offline");
        Elements IDs = document.select("input.friendCheckbox");

        //Attribute
        PlayerMiniProfile = MiniProfile.attr("data-miniprofile");
        PlayerID = IDs.attr("data-steamid");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: maybe because it is not there (fx element is added from javascript)

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. If I use `String htm = "html from question"; Document document = Jsoup.parse(html); ...[rest of your code]` then `PlayerMiniProfile` will contain `351983022` and `PlayerID` `76561198312248750`. This suggests that you are not parsing structure you may think you are. Try printing `document` (or at least `MiniProfile` element) to see if it contains `input` or if that input contains `data-steamid` attribute. It is possible that it could be added later by JavaScript. In that case jsoup is not best tool here. Use web-driver instead like Selenium.

Comment: it works with the small html above. this is the wohle site: http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198043477283/friends/coplay/ Dont know why i cant get the "data-steamid"